# How can I stop Lollipop ignoring my wifi network?

Tags: wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop

Android 5.0 has a new "feature": If a wifi network has no connection to the internet, it will remain connected to it but route traffic over mobile data instead. A small exclamation mark shows in the status bar over the wifi symbol.

Unfortunately, for some reason Android has decided that my home wifi does not have a good internet connection - which is not true, as I'm using it to access Stackexchange at the moment - and is, instead, trying to send everything over GPRS.

With mobile data disabled, things work over wifi just fine, despite the exclamation mark - so it isn't a problem with the wifi not working, per se.

Is there any way to override this "smart" feature? The only way I have found to make things work at the moment is to disable mobile data while I am in my house - which is not a practical long-term solution.

EDITING to add that I have now solved this problem by buying a new router! I was using something *very* old... But, I'll leave the question here for the benefit of anybody else with the same difficulty.

Comment: I'm a developer and I connect to a special device via WiFi, I've the same problem but I've no solution for now. Let me know if you find a something, thanks.

Comment: I remember there is a similar option to enable/disable this on KitKat, but yeah, I don't know why Google removed it on Lollipop. Then, there is a WiFi dropping case on Nexus 4 that made this a lot worse.

Comment: @Andrew What are you talking about on Kitkat? Please explain :)

Comment: @Seraphim ah, I was talking about "Avoid poor connection" on Jellybean and KitKat WiFi advanced setting, which I don't see it anymore on Lollipop. I thought it's replaced by "Aggresive WiFi to Cellular handover" on developer menu, but it seems I was wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [disable captive portal detection](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100657). In the terminal, or in `adb shell`, issue the command

```
settings put global captive_portal_detection_enabled 0
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 3):

When you are connected to your home wifi do you see the notification to 'Sign into Wi-Fi network'? If you tap on that item and then the 3 dots menu you will have the option to 'Use this network as is.' I'm in a similar situation as [@Seraphim's host](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/25160/seraphims-host) and so far this solution seems to be working.

edit: This solution isn't working 100% fo my situation, hopefully it will help for yours though.

Comment: No, I don't see that.

Comment: This option is on the "Sign in to network" dialog/screen - see [here](http://imgur.com/epTIGff).

Comment: @Mr.Buster ...which would be great, if I ever saw that screen :-) Presumably that page is only shown if Android thinks it is behind a captive portal.