# Issues with limited internet connectivity (photos, wifi)

Tags: wi-fi, internet, google-plus-photos

There are a host of issues that you run into when running stock Android in a country that blocks Google's servers. The first issue you run into is the setup wizard getting stuck trying to do updates. I already found [a workaround](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1774672) for that one. But I can't figure out how to fix the following:

- Wi-fi connections always show "Connected, no Internet" with an exclamation point icon.
- Doesn't automatically connect to saved wi-fi locations because it thinks there is no Internet.
- Photos app doesn't show any photos at all except when Airplane mode is on or when connected to a VPN.

Other issues such as the Play store not working are to be expected. But I wish I had workarounds for the 3 issues above. The "Connected, no Internet" warning must be using some Google service to detect connectivity. Can it be changed to use some other service that is not blocked? The Photos app not showing photos seems an unexcusable offense because the photos are stored locally and browsable with a file explorer. Why does Google need to go online at all to display photos on the phone?

Comment: Related: [How to disable captive portal detection? How to remove exclamation mark on Wi-Fi or signal icon in Lollipop?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/100657/16575) Also see the questions in that question's "Linked" section for more, e.g. [How can I stop Lollipop ignoring my wifi network?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/87907/16575)

Comment: Glad to read! May I suggest you [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) then – or shall we close your question as duplicate to one of the mentioned links? The remaining one (photos app) should be [put in a separate question post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/192154).

Comment: @Izzy I thought the questions were related because they have to do with inability to access Google's servers. I'm fine with closing this though. I'll go ahead and ask about the Photos app separately.

Comment: Correct approach :) From your answer I see we shall close this one as duplicate to the first one I've linked in my first comment. Good luck for the remaining #3 question!